# Replace by nothing and remove the line

Tags: php, regex

In a file, I replace a marker `!!marker!!` by a string or nothing:

```
if ($foo){
        insert_content('index.html', 'index.html', '!!marker!!', $string);
    }else{
        insert_content('index.html', 'index.html', '!!marker!!', '');
    }
```

…but as `!!marker!!` was on its own blank line, this line remains, and blank.

Is it possible to replace the marker by nothing and remove the line it was on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[^\n]*!!marker!![^\n]*\n
```

This should remove the line .Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/112

```
$re = "/[^\\n]*!!marker!![^\\n]*\\n/im";
$str = "asdasdasd\nsadasd !!marker!!a asdasd\nklklkl\na\nsd\nas\nd\n";
$subst = "";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: Thank you @vks can you help me how to use it with `str_replace` or something similar?